# How do I prevent an infinite loop when using an If statement inside of a Do loop?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a simple program that displays the output of a loop to the inside of a list box. The user would enter a number into a *From* text box. They would enter a number into a *To* text box. I need a conditional that only lets the program proceed if the *From* number is less than the *To* number. The program works until the *From* number is bigger than the *To* number, then it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.
The code looks like this:

```
    Dim intFrom As Integer
    Dim intTo As Integer
    Dim intNum As Integer = 1
    Integer.TryParse(txtFrom.Text, intFrom)
    Integer.TryParse(txtTo.Text, intTo)
    lstNumbers.Items.Clear()
    Do
        If intFrom < intTo Then
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(intNum)
            intNum += 1
        End If
    Loop Until intNum > intTo

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a for statement? [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement).

Comment: Please note that VBA <> VB.NET. You're using the latter.

Comment: In your loop, as soon as `intFrom` equals `intTo`, the `If` block will be skipped. So, `intNum` is never incremented further leading to an infinite loop. You need to either use `If intFrom <= intTo` or `Loop Until intNum >= intTo`. That said, you don't actually need the `If` statement. Just use `Do Until ... Loop` instead of `Do ... Loop Until`.

Comment: If the user enters the numbers the wrong way round, just swap them over? If we can find ways around basic problems that users cause, rather than bombarding them with error messages and rules they have to follow, it makes for a smoother UI experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just skip the loop if your condition is false

```
    Dim intFrom As Integer
    Dim intTo As Integer
    Dim intNum As Integer = 1
    Integer.TryParse(txtFrom.Text, intFrom)
    Integer.TryParse(txtTo.Text, intTo)
    lstNumbers.Items.Clear()
    If intFrom < intTo Then
        Do
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(intNum)
            intNum += 1
        Loop Until intNum > intTo
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Or better, get rid of the `If` statement altogether and use `Do Until intNum > intTo ... Loop`.